# Strange "There is a pending suggested edit" message while editing a post

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, error-message

I was editing a post this morning and when I tried to submit it I got the message below.

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in few minutes.

I'm not quite sure if this is so desired or just a logging output, where it should not be. For me it was quite strange, so I report it.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

The message is correct. Two persons tried to do a suggested edit at the same time. The other person was first, so his suggested edit is entered in the queue. You have to wait until that process is done.

The remaining 'bug' is that the message isn't very nice. It could show a nice dialog, which also preserves your edit. I think it is good to change your post into a feature request.